# Convert python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I have a python code .By this code i can searching in all column table. i want to convert that code to javaScript 
my python code is :

```
cmd_str = '&filter='
fields = {'f1': 'v1', 'f2': None, 'f3': 34, 'f4': datetime.now()}
for f, v in fields.items():
if v is not None:
if type(v) is str:
cmd_str += '%s|%s' % (f, v)
elif type(v) is datetime:
cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, type(v).__name__, v.isoformat())
else:
cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, type(v).__name__, v)
cmd_str += ','
cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1]
print(cmd_str)
```

I convert myself but I have some problems

```
var cmd_str = '&filter=';
var fields = {
    f1 : 'v1',
    f2 : '',
    f3 : 34
    f4 : datetime.now()
};
var i;
for( i = 0; i<fields.length; i++)
{
    if(fields[i][key] !='')
    {
        if(typeof fields[i][key] === string)
        {
            cmd_str += '%s|%s' % (fields[i][key]);
        }
        else if(typeof fields[i][key] === Date)
        {
            cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v.isoformat())
        }
        else
        {
            cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v);
            cmd_str += ',';
            cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1];
        }
    }
}
```

Can you fix problems for me?
I dont know this line is ok in javaScript:

```
  cmd_str += '%s|%s' % (fields[i][key]);
  cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v.isoformat())
  cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v);
  cmd_str += ',';
  cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1];
```

Comment: Can you tell us what are the problems you're facing?

Comment: I think `datetime` is not valid in JS. Try using `new Date()`?

Comment: also `typeof` returns a string in javascript. Can't compare to `Date` object

Comment: I dont know this line is ok in javaScript:

  ‍`cmd_str += '%s|%s' % (fields[i][key]);‍`
 `cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v.isoformat())`
  `cmd_str += '{}[{}]={}'.format(f, typeof v.__name__, v);`
 `cmd_str += ',';`
 `cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think few mistakes which i can see is
1) Loop structure is wrong . I didn't get what is key.
2) use instance of to check date. Because date is a object so when you do typeof(fields.f4) it will give you result as object. which is not required now.
3)for comma i am putting comma after every condition and at last taking sub string after removing last comma. 
I tried code like this.

```
var cmd_str = '&filter=';
var fields = {
f1 : 'v1',
f2 : '',
f3 : 34,
f4 : new Date()
};
var i;
for(i in fields)
{
  if(fields[i]!='')
{
    if(typeof(fields[i]) === "string")
    {
        cmd_str += i +'|'+ fields[i]+',';
    }
    else if(fields[i] instanceof Date)
    {
        cmd_str += i +'[datetime]='+ fields[i]+',';
    }
    else
    {
        cmd_str += i + typeof (fields[i])+"="+fields[i];
        cmd_str += ',';

    }
  }
} 
cmd_str = cmd_str.substring(0, cmd_str.length - 1);
```

Comment: thanks , but after each field should be a comma , and last field comma most be remove

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing about JS in your code,

1. string objects does not have `format` function
2. `%` is only numeric operator and doesn't format your string, `'string' % anything = NaN`
3. Date does not have `isoformat` function use `toISOString()`
4. JS not supporting python array `[:index]` style

Answer (score 0):

I changed to this code :

```
var cmd_str = '&filter=';
var fields = {
f1 : 'v1',
f2 : '',
f3 : 34
f4 : new Date()
};
var i;
for( i = 0; i<fields.length; i++)
{
  if(fields[i][key] !='')
{
    if(typeof fields[i][key] === string)
    {
        cmd_str += fields[i] +'|'+ fields[i][key];
    }
    else if(typeof fields[i][key] === new Date())
    {
        cmd_str += fields[i] +'[datetime]='+ fields[i][key];
    }
    else
    {
        cmd_str += fields[i] +'[typeof fields[i][key]]='+ fields[i][key];
        cmd_str += ',';
        cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1];
    }
  }
}
```

Is it right?
I don't know how fix this line `cmd_str = cmd_str[:-1];` to remove last Comma ,

Comment: No still this code is not right few points
1) What is key.
2) type of date is Object . you are doing that wrong use instanceof for date

Comment: the key. i mean value

Comment: key is not reserved word

Comment: how can i fix it for date?

Comment: How can I get the value in fields[i]?

Comment: Check my answer . Run it . If i skipped something or any confusion from yours side just comment i will try to help. Happy coding

Comment: thanks Roli, but after each field should be a comma , and last field comma most be remove